# Print Spooler Service to Automatic (Delayed Start) causes Error 87

Tags: services, print-spooler

I'm running Windows Vista SP2 Home Premium 32-Bit, with a Lexmark X5450 All-In-One Printer.

Whenever I try to change the Print Spooler Service from `Automatic/Manual/Disabled` to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
The delayed auto-start flag could not be set.



Error 87: The parameter is incorrect.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And the Print Spooler Service doesn't change its Startup Type. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What OS? Windows?

Comment: What are you using to make the change? Is it running as admin? You could check the registry to see if the `Services\Spooler` key, and particularly the `RequiredPrivileges` value is damaged.

Comment: @Dennis Windows Vista SP2 Home Premium

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, I'm admin, using `services.msc`. I'll try what you said... EDIT: What should the `RequiredPrivileges` value be? For me, it's `SeTcbPrivilege
SeImpersonatePrivilege
SeAuditPrivilege
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
SeLoadDriverPrivilege
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
SeBackupPrivilege
SeRestorePrivilege
`

Comment: Hmm, I don’t know what it should be in Vista, and it might be different depending on OS type, service-packs, printer-drivers, etc., but in Windows 7, I’ve got SeTcbPrivilege
`SeImpersonatePrivilege
SeAuditPrivilege
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
SeLoadDriverPrivilege` (in that order).

Have you installed a printer or printing software recently?

Comment: @Synetech I installed a printer [Lexmark X5450 All-In-One Printer], but that was ~4 years ago. Of course, this problem has been around for a long time, too.

Comment: I just tried it myself using the Services MMC snap-in, the service-controller, and even manually setting it with the registry and none of them worked. I was able to set other services to delayed-auto and could set the spooler to other modes, but the spooler just does not want to be set to delayed-auto. o.O I’ll ask around to see if I can find any info on why it won’t…

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked in [a Windows Sysinternals thread](http://forum.sysinternals.com/the-delayed-autostart-flag-could-not-be-set_topic30715.html), and it seems like you cannot set the flag because some services are part of a service group, which is controlled by the ServiceGroupList in the registry. Since services often depend on other services, some cannot be delayed.

However, third-party tools such as [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/) are able to delay some services.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete `Group` value from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Spooler` then after system restart you will be able to set Spooler startup type to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`. Not the cleanest solution but it worked for me.